# Map stored procedure with multiple resultset returned in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am currently migrating an already established website from old ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core 2.2. The database is a shared database across other platforms and is also established therefore I cannot just changed anything from it.

I came across to this problem when I had to call a stored procedure from EF Core where this stored procedure returns 3 result sets. The result set of the stored procedure is like this.

**Table 1**

```
ColumnName1 | ColumnName2 | SomeColumn | AndMoreColumns
------------+-------------+------------+---------------
Value1      | value 2     | value 3    | Value 4
```

**Table 1**

```
Column1    | Column2
-----------+----------
value1     | value 2
```

**Table 3**

```
Column1
-------
Value1
```

Table 1 and table 2 are related to each other. This table will always return 1 row on table 1 and table 2 can return multiple rows while table 3 is static.

Now, my question is. How do I map this result set to an EF Core `Query<T>` model builder? I want to map it per column name since I want to make the column names more friendly. An example that I had that did not work is like this.

```
modelBuilder.Query<MyModel>(a => 
{
    a.Property(b=>b.ModelId).HasColumnName("ColumnName1");
    a.Property(b=>b.ModelName).HasColumnName("ColumnName2");
    ...
});
```

but unfortunately, the above mapping did not work. Especially for the 2nd table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First at all, the result from stored procedure is not a table, I mean an user table.

So, I think there are two possible solutions for your question:

1. Work with pure ADO.NET, execute data reader and cast the result to result models
2. Use an external approach from EF Core

For point 1, please read this question: [EF Core query stored procedure map to types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041769/ef-core-query-stored-procedure-map-to-types/53060399#53060399)

For point 2, please read this question: [Working with multiple resultset in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740636/working-with-multiple-resultset-in-net-core)

Also you can read this issue: [Support multiple resultsets #8127](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8127)

Let me know if this answer is useful.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at a lot of different posts and examples on various sites and landed on a GitHub string of responses.

However, the solutions I found on GitHub seemed like a lot of extra work to me, and limit things to 1, 2 or 3 result sets (reference this post: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8127).

Instead, I first created a simplified extension method (based upon what I saw in the GitHub posts, except without the asynchronous logic):

```
public static class TranslateResultSet
{
    public static List<T> LoadListFromDbReader<T>(this DbDataReader reader)
    {
        List<T> resultSetValues = (List<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)));
        List<String> columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            if (obj == null)
            {
                throw new Exception(@"Cannot create object from type '" + typeof(T).Name + "'");
            }
            foreach (String column in columns)
            {
                var value = reader[column] == DBNull.Value ? null : reader[column];
                obj!.GetType().GetProperty(column)?.SetValue(obj, value);
            }
            resultSetValues!.Add((T)obj);
        }
        return resultSetValues;
    }
}
```

and then called it in a foreach loop for each result set (4 results in my case):

```
public class QueryStoredProcedureWithMultipleResults
{
    public Query_Result1 result1 { get; set; } = new Query_Result1();
    public List<Query_Result2> result2 { get; set; } = new List<Query_Result2>();
    public List<Query_Result3> result3 { get; set; } = new List<Query_Result3>();
    public List<Query_Result4> result4 { get; set; } = new List<Query_Result4>();

    public QueryStoredProcedureWithMultipleResults(DbContext dbContext,
        String parm1,
        DateTime parm2,
        String parm3)
    {
        DbCommand cmd = null;
        DbDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            cmd = dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
            if (cmd.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
            }
            cmd.CommandText = @"SprocName";
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parm1", parm1));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parm2", parm2));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parm3", parm3));
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // first, load a list of count values from various tables in the database (Query_Result0 is the same as
            // Query_Result1, except every property is nullable, and the .Val() extension methods return a non-null
            // value for every data type after checking to see if it is null or not).

            foreach (var result in TranslateResultSet.LoadListFromDbReader<Query_Result0>(reader))
            {
                result1.p_num_count1 = result.p_num_count1.Val();
                result1.p_num_count2 = result.p_num_count2.Val();
                result1.p_dollar_amount1 = result.p_dollar_amount1.Val();
                // etc.
                break;
            }
            reader.NextResult();
            foreach (var result in TranslateResultSet.LoadListFromDbReader<Query_Result2>(reader))
            {
                result2.Add(result);
            }
            reader.NextResult();
            foreach (var result in TranslateResultSet.LoadListFromDbReader<Query_Result3>(reader))
            {
                result3.Add(result);
            }
            reader.NextResult();
            foreach (var result in TranslateResultSet.LoadListFromDbReader<Query_Result4>(reader))
            {
                result4.Add(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Abend in QueryStoredProcedureWithMultipleResults", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.DisposeAsync();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            cmd.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var dashboard = new QueryStoredProcedureWithMultipleResults(dbContext, parm1, parm2, parm3);
```

It works for me in Entity Framework Core 7.0.11 and is very similar to the ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.Translate approach from Entity Framework 6.2 (and the .Net Framework).