# Executing raw SQL stored procedure from Entity Framework Core and want to return multiple result sets

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, stored-procedures

I have a requirement, where a stored procedure returns 2 results (has 2 select queries). I want to be able to read these 2 different tables at the same time.

How can I do so? Please advice

Comment: UNION ALL perhaps?

Comment: Does it have to be EF? Dapper has a `QueryMultiple` API that is ideal for this, but: it won't plug into the EF pieces - it is entirely standalone (intended for populating POCOs, reading simple data, etc)

Comment: the fact that [this issue is still open](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8127) suggests "nope, not supported in EF"

Comment: Hi Puja, StackOverflow is not a free consulting service. There are many people eager to help, but we'd like you to share with us what you have tried so far (your code, including things like encountered error messages), showing that you've researched a thing or two. Having said that, reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56880399/map-stored-procedure-with-multiple-resultset-returned-in-ef-core might prove useful to you.

Comment: @Thailo in this case, I think the question is perfectly reasonable, as is the lack of code for a very clearly explained use-case (thanks puja), about an API that *simply doesn't exist*. It is very hard to give an example of what you've tried to do when an API that **absolutely should be there**: isn't. So *on this occasion*: I strongly disagree that puja could have done anything better. Good job puja!

Comment: Thanks MArc, Thailo you both have given me quick insite on the issue.